# jQuery - Validate that two different <li>'s has been selected

Tags: jquery

For an online booking system I have the user put in a pickup and destination by postcode. The problem is that the user can search an address, e.g. 'LE115GU' and it will show multiple results. At the moment the user can go to the next page of the booking form without selecting an address so it doesn't write the address to the database. I basically need to put a validation in there so that if the user doesn't select an `li-addr-res` for either pickup or destination, they are prompted with an alert.

This is what happens if a user searches a postcode:-

[image]

So something like:-

```
if(nextPgeNum == 2) { 

 // CODE // if title="Dropoff" and no li-addr-res is selected

 // or if title="Pickup" and no li-addr-res is selected

 // alert("You must select a pickup or dropoff address")

}
```

I'm just not too sure how I can achieve this so any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the HTML code for the dropoff.

```
 <div id="cp-row-wrapper-dp" class="row-wrapper row-wrapper-addr-search" title="Dropoff">

    <div class="div-search-label left">

        <p class="a-topheader-infotext">

    <strong>Destination</strong>

    </p>

</div>

<div class="div-search-content div-content left div-subrow-style ui-corner-all">

    <input id="txt-dropoff-hn" class="input-txt-xxxsml input-txt-highlight addr-ho-input left" type="text" value="" maxlength="5" size="4" tabindex="3" name="txt-dropoff-hn">

    <input id="txt-dropoff" class="input-txt-xmed input-txt-highlight required validate-from-db addr-search-input txt-dropoff left default success" type="text" tabindex="4" name="txt-dropoff" autocomplete="off">

    <input class="hidden-lat-lng" type="hidden" value="">

    <input id="txt-hidden-dp" class="hidden-post-code" type="hidden" name="txt-hidden-dp" value="">

    <input class="hidden-route-leg" type="hidden" value="2">

    <button id="cp-search-dest" class="btn-med ui-button ui-state-default ui-button-text-only ui-corner-all btn-hover-anim btn-row-wrapper left ui-state-hover" name="btn-row-wrapper">Search</button>

    <ul class="ul-addr-res ul-result-view" style="visibility: visible; display: block;">

    <li class="li-addr-res">

    <p class="p-addr-res" style="cursor: pointer;" tabindex="0">PRINCE WILLIAM ROAD, LOUGHBOROUGH, LE115GU</p>

    </li>

    <li class="li-addr-res">


    <p class="p-addr-res" style="cursor: pointer;" tabindex="1">ARTHUR JONES MOTORS, 6A, PRINCE WILLIAM ROAD, LOUGHBOROUGH, LE115GU</p>

    </li>

    <li class="li-addr-res">

    <p class="p-addr-res" style="cursor: pointer;" tabindex="2">BROMAKIN LTD, 10, PRINCE WILLIAM ROAD, LOUGHBOROUGH, LE115GU</p>

    </li>

    <li class="li-addr-res">

    <p class="p-addr-res" style="cursor: pointer;" tabindex="3">C D M DUCTWORK, 17, PRINCE WILLIAM ROAD, LOUGHBOROUGH, LE115GU</p>

    </li>

    <li class="li-addr-res">

    <p class="p-addr-res" style="cursor: pointer;" tabindex="4">CHARNWOOD MOLECULAR, 13, PRINCE WILLIAM ROAD, LOUGHBOROUGH, LE115GU</p>

    </li>

    </ul>

    <div class="div-result-info div-pagenation-style" style="display: block;">

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You could set some kind of variable on the click event and test it for any value afterwards?

Comment: Or, when creating your lists, use radio buttons, and check if at least one is selected before continuing. I think that's the easiest way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I posted in the comments, one option would be use a list of radio buttons and check whether any of them has been selected before continuing. Something on these lines:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // On form submission
  $('#submit_button').click(function() {
    // Check if at least one of the radio buttons named 'test' has been selected
    if (!$("input[@name='test']:checked").val()) {
       alert('Nothing is checked!');
       return false;
    }
    else {
      alert('One of the radio buttons is checked!');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Every client side solution will be problematic because user can change client side scripts and settings. You could allow user to go to the next page and then check if database entry exists. If it does not exist, redirect him back to the previous step. Or you can check database entry when user clicks next ...

Comment: I just need to ensure an li address is selected before you can click 'Next Step', if you go to http://www.marandy.com/onlinebooking_htp/login-guest.php and press 'Next Step' it doesn't allow the user to go to the next step which is fine. But if you type LE115GU in the pickup address and then not select one of the addresses, it then allows you to go to the next step. I basically need some form of validation in there that will only allow the user to go to the next step if the li address has been selected

Comment: Error: Address server is taking too long to respond, please try again later. :) How do you label selected address? Do you set new background color?

Comment: It looks like there is a callback function assigned to a click event. So if that is also your case you can set 2 global variables (one for pickup and one for destination) and when user clicks on address just set the variable. When user wants to go to the next step, check if both variables are set and if they are, everything is ok.